# Does my text editor application have a memory leak? Why does it consume 3x more memory than Notepad

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks, qt4

I am writing a text Editor application. As an experiment I ran the application and monitered its memory usage on Task Manager as I performed different actions.

- When I first launched the application, it used 3000 kB.
- It stayed   roughly the same when I typed
- When I clicked on save, it shot up to 9000kb
- and then it just stayed at 8500kb (It didn't go back down to 3000kb)

Is this caused by a memory leak? I'm a bit confused because I observed similar behaviour with Notepad.

- Launching: 1500kb
- Saving: 6000 kb
- After saving, memory stays at around 5000kb

Also, why does my application take up 3x more memory than Notepad.exe, what kind of things could cause that? Should I be worried?

Comment: First of all "Task Manager" can't help in even diagnosing if there is any memory leak! Second: nobody will be able to tell whether your editor has a memory leak without source code / memory profiler...

Comment: Also, you are apparently using Qt4, which could probably explain why it uses more memory that notepad. Run a memory profiler on it and then you can worry.

Comment: Since you have a tag Qt I suppose you are using that framework. This will already take up a lot of memory compared to using direct win32 api calls.

Comment: Simple test - click on "save" again. If memory usage goes up *another* 6MB, then you have a serious memory leak in the "save" code. If it only goes back up to 9MB, then "save" has allocated some resources that are not freed when it finishes, but they *are* reused for future saves, so strictly speaking that is not a 5.5MB leak (doesn't prove anything about small leaks). If nothing else, there's no guarantee when you free memory that the process actually returns memory to the OS. It usually stays allocated to the process, and the process can use it to satisfy future memory allocations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with you want to know where that memory is actually being used. There are a lot of complex programs to do memory analysis/profiling, but if you want something more detailed than Task Manager but still fairly simple and free, Sysinternals vmmap is great.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd535533

As others have mentioned, the save is probably causing other libraries to be pulled in. The text itself is also going to contribute to your memory usage. VMMap will help you determine how much is yours and how much is other stuff. Then you could see if your part is really growing substantially over time or not. You probably want a large amount of time of stress testing to really see if it is leaking memory if you are not going to use a memory profiler, otherwise the leak is probably not going to be big enough to really notice easily.

Answer (score 1):

The File-Save dialog starting up for the first time probably burns a lot of memory. Opening the file dialog embeds a copy of Explorer in the window, for instance, and loading Explorer into your process carries a lot of baggage along with it.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you are using Qt means there's a lots of unnecessary code added to your software. Qt Core for instance is over 2MB, Qt Gui is about 8 MB. Microsoft on the other hand have probably coded Notepad using pure C/C++ and the Windows API, which mean they have a smaller and faster executable.

Finally, it also depends on your compiler. MinGW is going to create larger and slower executables than Visual C++ compiler. So if you can, try to use Microsoft's compiler.

Answer (score 0):

I tried exactly the same in notepad, the save needs more memory. If you open a current file and save it, then there is no difference in memory. Creating the file takes tons of memory, in the end.